# How can I extract the measurelength, highmeasure and lowmeasure of routes in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, linear-referencing

I'm trying to create road Routes in ArcGIS, which traditionally have been created using workstation. I've managed to write a Python script to do this, however, unlike ArcInfo, the attributes MEASURELENGTH, LOWMEASURE and HIGHMEASURE are not automatically created as you could do with the WorkStation 'routestats' command.

Anyone know how to do this in ArcGIS or Python?

Comment: Have you looked at the Linear Referencing tools in ArcToolbox?

Comment: I don't use Low measure and High Measure unless they fall at the line ends.  I only use from measure and to measure, which are !Shape.FirstPoint.M! and !Shape.LastPoint.M! and the measure length between the two is ABS(!Shape.LastPoint.M! - !Shape.FirstPoint.M!).  I do use a formula for MMonotonicity to detect routes that are not continuously increasing and could adapt it to find the low and high measure if I wanted to (I don't).  That formula is here:  https://geonet.esri.com/message/196206#196206

Comment: Have looked at the Linear Referencing tools - are using Create Routes and Calibrate Routes tools to create the routes.

Comment: Following your lead @Richard, I looked into the  arcpy.Geometry http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000  but haven't been able to successfully get, for instance, the polyline M geometry length, which I'm hoping would have returned the polyline route length (as opposed to the polyline arc length).  I couldn't even get their code sample they have at the bottom of the page working - it said " 'Polyline' object has no attribute 'Length' ".

Comment: How are you developing your code?  The examples I have given work in the Field Calculator with the Python option.  The example does not work in the field calculator and would only work in the Python window or in .py file run from Idle or another Python IDE.  If you used Create Route and your measures should be continuously increasing, then my formula would work to get measure length as opposed to geometry length (i.e., if gaps were measured then that measure length is reported by the ABS(!Shape.LastPoint.M! - !Shape.FirstPoint.M!) calculation.)  Length will only return geometry length.

Comment: Have just tried !Shape.FirstPoint.M! in the field Calculate tool in ArcMap on a handful of routes which seems to be working, thanks! Although one of the routes seems to be reporting LastPoint as the start (ie. zero measure) and FirstPoint as the last (max measure).

Comment: That could be real.  Run the MMonotonicity calculation on that route to see if it has continuously decreasing measures or if it has complex measures.  Complex measures occur when routes have branching and looping due to self-intersection.  Only simple lines with no self-intersections can be continuously increasing.  Create Route cannot deal with full circles.  When it encounters a full circle it obliterates the geometry into scrambled line segments so that the route becomes a meaningless mess.  Circles have to be built in part using separate runs with assigned measures and manually merged.

Comment: You could have continuously decreasing measures because you built that route with the opposite coordinate priority from the orientation used during the calibration step.  That would be expected if they are oriented in opposite directions.  I assign my Centerlines with a coordinate priority field with LL, LR, UL, UR and do selections and separate Create route runs for all 4.

Comment: Hi @Richard. Re coordinate priority, I sort of understand, but I'm trying to automate the state's road network of 2700+ routes, so if you mean try each of the four options and manually inspect each to see which one works correctly, I don't think this is possible?

Comment: In trying to verify the routes are being created ok, I'm trying to compare the route length of the last set of routes generated (using ArcInfo Workstation). In the output from Workstation I have total MEASURELENGTH, LOWMEASURE & HIGHMEASURE. For example, for Midland Hwy which has 3 road breaks I have chainages (metres) of 419080, 0 & 451644. With ArcGIS I get !Shape.LastPoint.m! = 0, !Shape.FirstPoint.m! = 206655 (which is actaully the chainage at the start of the 2nd section of the road (i.e. after the 1st road break).

Comment: The Identify Route Locations tool returns values that indicate the route created is fine... Minimum Measure: 0.000, Maximum Measure: 451644.000, Measure Values: Strictly Increasing, Parts: 3     If I could return/calculate these values to fields I would able to complete the integrity checks.

Comment: The calculations I already gave you do all of that.  The Mmonotonicity calculation is the Strictly Increasing value.  The number of parts is returned by !Shape.PartCount!.  If measures are Strictly increasing then the From measure of the line will be the Minimum Measure and the To measure of the line will be the Maximum Measure.  I only use the Identify Route Locations tool to actually identify the measure of a specific location along a route, not for the route statistics.  If the mmonotonicity of a route isn't Strictly Increasing or Strictly Decreasing I consider the Min and Max meaningless.

Comment: Am confused as to why the Mmonotonicity calculation is returning '4' (strictly decreasing) when ArcMap's Identify Route Locations tool says it is '1' (strictly increasing). Plotting events (e.g. assets with a surveyed measure) onto the calibrated route places them in the correct location, hence verifying by my way of thinking that the route is strictly increasing not decreasing. 
Checking the initial un-calibrated route, the measures/route direction runs the other way and has a Mmonotonicity = 1.

Comment: Hence, I'm thinking that when calibrated, if the route direction is essentially flipped from the default in the initial Create Route, the Mmonotonicity calculation somehow carries through or knows the original route actually went in the opposite direction and thus Mmonotonicity  = 1 is also essentially flipped, and becomes 4, and visa versa. Sound right?

Comment: Also, with your comment on Mar 13 at 7:11 re coordinate priority, do you mean you would trial each of LL, LR, UL, UR in turn until you get a route that has Mmonotonicity  = 1 ? I think this might be what is causing issues with a few roads where the resultant route is Mmonotonicity  = 5 and the measures are all over the place, so to speak.  Thanks for your help so far Richard, most appreciated!